# collectionFormat: multi not working with Perl Mojolicious Swagger2

Tags: perl, yaml, swagger, mojolicious

I'm trying to make my API support multiple parameters of the same name: e.g.

```
/myAPI/search?myfield=1&myfield=2&myfield=3
```

I'm using Perl and cpan modules Mojolicious and Swagger2

My swagger file (yaml) has this definition (is validated):

```
/search:
    get:
      x-mojo-controller: "Search"
      operationId: search
      description: Search
      parameters:
        - name: myfield
          description: Array of types
          in: query
          type: array
          collectionFormat: multi
          uniqueItems: true
          items:
            type: string
          required: false
```

My controller looks like this:

```
package myAPI::Controller::Search;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';
sub search {
    my( $self, $args, $cb ) = @_;
    $self->render(text => Dumper $args);
}
```

When args are dumped to browser the 'myfield' field appears to be an array, yet it only ever has the last value in it.

```
$VAR1 = { 'myfield' => [ '3' ] };
```

Swagger2 version is:

```
our $VERSION = '0.83';
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're making your example up or you might have some hooks that mess up the input. The test below runs successfully:

```
use Mojo::Base -strict;
use Test::Mojo;
use Test::More;

package MyApp::Example;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';

sub search {
  my ($self, $args, $cb) = @_;
  $self->$cb($args, 200);
}

package main;
use Mojolicious::Lite;
plugin Swagger2 => {url => 'data://main/multi-param.json'};

my $t = Test::Mojo->new;
$t->get_ok('/search?myfield=1&myfield=2&myfield=3')->status_is(200)->json_is('/myfield', [1, 2, 3]);

done_testing;

__DATA__
@@ multi-param.json
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {"version": "1.0", "title": "Test multi"},
  "paths": {
    "/search": {
      "get": {
        "x-mojo-controller": "MyApp::Example",
        "operationId": "search",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "myfield",
            "in": "query",
            "type": "array",
            "collectionFormat": "multi",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": { "type": "string" },
            "required": false
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {"description": "whatever", "schema": {"type": "object"}}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There's already a test for this: https://github.com/jhthorsen/swagger2/blob/master/t/multi-param.t

Comment: You are right ! I discovered a 'hook' that was manipulating the parameters. Thanks for the steer !

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try out this plugin instead: https://metacpan.org/release/Mojolicious-Plugin-OpenAPI

It's plays more along with the "mojolicious rules", meaning you would extract the params like this:

```
sub search {
  my $c = shift->openapi->valid_input or return; 
  my $values = $c->every_param("myfield");
  $c->reply->openapi(200 => $values);
}
```